# Gotify executable not executing

Tags: terminal, raspberry-pi, raspberry-pi3, raspbian

I am trying to setup gotify server on my Raspberry Pi 3 B+ .I am following [this](https://letsfoss.com/setting-up-gotify-in-raspberry-pi/) tutorial.I downloaded,unzipped and made executable the `gotify-linux-arm-7.zip` file /

When I do `ls`
Result is [image: It shows the executable file]

But after `sudo ./gotify-linux-arm-7`
I get [image: error]

Please suggest how to overcome this error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue was minor but needs to be remembered. My RPi 3B + supports arm64 and I had downloaded arm 7 version looking at youtube and other online sources. Installing the arm64 version solved the issue .